# 4x TPIC6B595 + 4x 7 segment display

Tags: arduino-nano, shift-register, 7-segment

I am going to use 4x TPIC6B595 and 4x 7 segment display with common anode.
Below You Can find vendor site of this display.
https://sklep.avt.pl/wyswietlacz-led-2-30-57mm-zielony-wa.html

Here is my diagram:
[image: diagram]

I want to display 4 digit number. Will it work? Or do i need also MIC2981 chip to supply more current?

I didn't use shift registers like TPIC before. Could You show me a basic code to make display show 4 digit number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case you don't need the MIC2981 to switch the anodes because the anodes can be continuously powered. In your previous attempt, which used a single shift register and multiplexing, it was necessary to switch the anodes. Check that 9 volts is enough before proceeding too far. 12volts is probably better with that display.
You may find this project helpful as a code example: https://github.com/HeikkiHietala/large-7-segment-led-display/blob/master/Arduino-bigdigit03-clock.ino

Comment: Thank You for Your big support! That's what I need.